# datatable re-order on deleting a row

Tags: jquery

Im new to jquery. I have a table with only one row and a button to display initially. a new row is being added on click of a button and the row number in the td(serial number) is incremented. Now, when i delete the table, the number ordering will be missed. how to re-order the numbers on delete.

```
var i = 1; //adding the row 
var k=1;
$("#add_ExpenseRow").click(function() {
    $('.datepicker').datepicker('destroy');
    myTr = $("#expense_table tbody tr:first").clone(true);
    myTr.find("input[type='text']").val('');
    myTr.show();
    myTr.appendTo("#expense_table tbody");
    var x = $("#expense_table tbody tr").length-1;
    for(k; k<x; k++){
        $("#expense_table tbody tr td:first").text(k+2);
    }
    //deleting the row
    $('#expense_table').delegate(".delRow",'click', function() {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var rowCount = $('#expense_table tr').length;
$("#add_ExpenseRow").click(function () {
    myTr = $("#expense_table tbody tr:first").clone(true);
    myTr.find("input[type='text']").val('');
    myTr.show();
    myTr.appendTo("#expense_table tbody");
    rowCount++;

    myTr.find("td:first").text(rowCount);
})

//deleting the row
$('#expense_table').delegate(".delRow", 'click', function () {
    //don't allow to delete if the last row
    if (rowCount == 1) {
        return;
    }
    var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
    $tr.nextAll().find('td:first').text(function (i, text) {
        return parseInt($.trim(text)) - 1;
    })
    $tr.remove();
    rowCount--;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/zuX4a/)

Comment: It worked for me. i would appreciate your help in getting this thing done.

Answer (score 0):

iterate over all tr's of the table and reassign the row number:

```
var number = 0;
$("#expense_table tbody tr").each(function(tr) {
  number++;
  $(tr).find("td:first").text(number);
});
```

after that the numbers will be ascending again